# SOLR with tomcat - large amount of processes

Tags: tomcat, solr

I am currently serving solr using tomcat6, however I have noticed that when I run top there are a large number of java processes being run by the tomcat user.

```
22738 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22739 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:02.18 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22740 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.50 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22741 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:01.75 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22742 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22743 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22744 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22745 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22746 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:02.14 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22747 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:03.79 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22748 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22749 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:17.44 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22752 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22753 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.04 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22754 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:02.37 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22755 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.13 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
22807 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:11.23 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
23496 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:06.58 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
30158 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:00.79 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
30159 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:12.65 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
30165 tomcat6   20   0  634M   98M  4072 S  0.0 12.9  0:02.02 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.
```

Is this normal? Or Can I control how many processes are spawned through configuration?

many thanks